# Logo is not displaying and changes are not updating properly

Tags: wordpress, caching, plugins

I am new to WordPress, currently working part-time in an institute as IT support. I occasionally make minor changes to the site. this is the site. https://targettraining.edu.au/
I have 2 issues now.

1. The logo is not displaying properly on site. It shows properly in the admin panel but not once I logged out. The caption "YOUR SUCCESS, OUR TRADITION" is not in the logo image and I searched the whole dashboard but couldn't find where the caption is entered.
2. If I add new content or changes to the site it's not getting updated right away but after a day. Similarly, I can see the changes in the admin portal not once I logged out.

The solutions I have tried through surfing the internet.

1. Cleared all cache in the browser, admin portal
2. There might be some plugin issues is another solution mentioned so tried deactivating all the plugins one by one and checked.
   nothing worked.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow (all of the Stack Exchange Network) must be self-contained. The primary purpose of Stack Overflow is for questions to be useful to future visitors. Questions which are basically: "go look at my site and fix it", are not useful to future visitors. This question might be good/useful, but you need to move enough code into the question so we know what you're asking without needing to go off-site to find out. Please see: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428)

Answer (score 3):

1. To resolve this issue, you need to simply hit CTRL + F5 (or Cmd + R in Mac) buttons on your keyboard to reload the page. This will ask the browser to reload the page by fetching a fresh version. In most cases, this would fix the issue.
2. Clear the plugin cache or deactivate the cache plugin and check.
3. Hosting like wpengine, bluehost, siteground have their own caching solution to improve your website performance. If you use wordpress hosting as I mentioned try to clear cache from there.
   https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-clear-your-cache-in-wordpress/